# Give an example of a sequence of functions having the following property.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I am finding an example of a sequence $(f_n)$ of differentiable functions on an interval $I$ such that $f_n\to 0$ uniformly on $I$ but $f'_n(x)\to \infty$ for all $x\in I$ as $n\to \infty$.Can someone provide me an example where this can occur.I was trying with trigonometric functions like $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)/n$ etc but they are not working.

Comment: @Chrystomath Why does the derivative tend to $\infty$?

Comment: @Chrystomath yes I agree with Rama Murthy.

Comment: I'm giving up on this, but perhaps there is such a function. Let $C_n(x)$ be the $n$th approximation of the Cantor-like staircase, and take $n(x-C_n(x))$. This doesn't work for the ternary Cantor set, but if you insert more gaps to make $|x-C_n(x)|<1/n^2$, it might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer: such an example has to be weird. Assuming continuity of  the derivatives I will show that no such sequence can exist.

Write $I$ as $\cup_m\{x:f_n'(x) \geq 1 \forall n >m\}$. By Baire Catrgory Theorem there is an integer $m$ and  interval $[a,b] \subset I$ (with $a <b$) such that $f_n'(t) >1$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ for all $n \geq m$. But now we get a contradiction from $f_n(b)-f_n(a)=\int_a^{b} f_n'(t)dt \geq b-a$ for all  $n >m$.

Comment: Your answer is fine...Please try if you can also find the complete solution in addition so that this post can be enriched further...